# Azure App Service optional incoming SSL certificate forces prompt in browsers

Tags: ssl, axios, azure-web-app-service, ssl-certificate

A simple ASP.NET Core 3.1 backend is running on an Azure App Service, where the Incoming Client Certificate option is set to Allow (the app integrates with other apps, using SSL certificate based authentication). Nothing was configured in Startup.cs to do any magic with the incoming certificates (where the app's interested in the incoming certificate, the controller just reads it via Request.Headers["X-ARR-ClientCert"])

However, a React frontend (running in another App Service) uses MSAL to authenticate with the backend App Service, using Azure Active Directory/OAuth 2, **not** SSL certificates, the X-ARR-ClientCert header is not populated at all (the HTTP client being axios).

Some users, when trying to access the app get a popup from seemingly all different browsers, asking to specify which certificate to use for authentication (Site "backend" needs your credentials):

[image: SSL certificate popup from Chrome]

Not all users are prompted with this popup, it happens seldomly. Is there any known way to configure either something in the App Service, React frontend (axios) or even in the Startup of the ASP.NET code to not-trigger this popup? In the App Service, it'd be impossible to put all routes into the Certificate exclusion path.

One idea seems to be to set rejectUnauthorized to false when setting up axios, however I'm unsure if this is a safe approach:

```
axios.create({
      httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
      })
    });
```

Comment: The `clientCertEnabled` : ‘false’ and `clientCertMode` : Optional can be set from Resource Explorer.
Kindly check this kudu [wiki Optional Client Cert](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Optional-Client-Cert) for more info. 

I believe you’re referring to this doc section: [Exclude paths from requiring authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/app-service-web-configure-tls-mutual-auth#exclude-paths-from-requiring-authentication)  -  to avoid “Client certificate prompt” for all URLs under the specified Path.

Comment: While I check on this further. As I understand in your case, the browser challenges once for the client cert and then never again (in the same session). Regardless of which certificate is select/not select, the subsequent requests are successful.